# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : one node produced an error: the condition has length > 1

Tags: r

i am runing a gridEZ algorithm then i encounter this error "Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
one node produced an error: the condition has length > 1"
which i believe it from this command lines,
print("starting cluster")
**clusterExport(cl, split(ls("package:raster"),1:length(ls("package:raster"))))

invisible(parLapply(cl, clump_info, EZ_gen_fn, max_cells_per_EZ=max_cells_per_EZ, output_path = output_path, run_ID = run_ID))
stopCluster(cl)**

print("EZ generation complete. Compiling EZ files and generating EZ rasters next")

because before the error, it has printed the "starting cluster" in the R console as below... so i believe the error is immedaitely after the print staring cluster...
**[1] "starting cluster"**
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
one node produced an error: the condition has length > 1

*Please can anyone help with this error?*

since the clump_info function accepts 'sett_mat' and 'strata_mat' as vector inputs. i converted the non matrices to matrices before proceeding with the rest of the function. This is to allow the function to handle both matrix and vector inputs for "sett_mat" and 'strata_mat'.